# How do i change the clicked button

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently i have 3 buttons with names **start_btn** , **about_btn** and **stats_btn** which are movieClips.All 3 of them are in a container (also a movieClip) with the name of **group_btn**.So my question is how do i tell the exact element to change its ScaleX and ScaleY when im using only one MouseEventListener for all 3 of them.
I did figure that ill have to detect which one is clicked but then ,after that i dont know what to do .
so i have this code so far :

```
private function onAddedToStage(eve:Event):void {
        trace("we are good to go");
        this.group_btn.start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, makeButtonBigger)
        this.group_btn.start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, makeButtonSmaller)
        this.group_btn.about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, makeButtonBigger)
        this.group_btn.about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, makeButtonSmaller)
        this.group_btn.stats_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, makeButtonBigger)
        this.group_btn.start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, makeButtonSmaller)

    }

private function makeButtonBigger(ev:MouseEvent):void{
        var nameOfButton:String = ev.currentTarget.name;
        //this.group_btn.nameOfButton.scaleX = 1.2  <--- doesnt work
        trace(nameOfButton)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the property using square brackets; the way you have it is implying that there's a button that's literally called 'nameOfButton', which is why it's failing. Try the following:

```
private function makeButtonBigger(ev:MouseEvent):void{
    var nameOfButton:String = ev.currentTarget.name;
    this.group_btn[nameOfButton].scaleX = 1.2;
    trace(nameOfButton);
}
```

That will use the actual captured string, rather than the variable name itself.

Although, you can also access the button directly from the event's `currentTarget` property:

```
private function makeButtonBigger(ev:MouseEvent):void{
    ev.currentTarget.scaleX = 1.2;
}
```